# RegEx Exactly Match Beginning and End of a String with a Wildcard in between

Tags: javascript, regex

I am searching strings with the following format: ABC-001

I would to construct a RegEx search from a user text input field so that I can search:

```
ABC* and match ABC-001, ABC-002, and so on...
ABC*2 and match ABC-002 but NOT ABC-012
ABC*12 and match ABC-012
```

I know I will need do some string manipulation to go from user input to a regular expression, but as an example I construct a regex like so:

```
^ABC.*2$
```

Unfortunately, this matches `ABC-002` and `ABC-012`.

Comment: I guess you need `^ABC-0*2$` where `2` is dynamic.

Comment: Can `ABC*2` match anything besides ABC-002, like ABC-102?

Comment: No, ABC*2 should only match ABC-002. Only a search for ABC*102 should match ABC-102.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this `replace` on user input:

```
var re = new RegExp(input.replace(/\*/g, '-0*'), "gi");
```

This will convert `ABC*2` to `/ABC-0*2/gi` regex and this will match `ABC-002` but won't match `ABC-012`.